# Multi plots in Julia

Tags: julia

Here is what I'd like to do : [image]

So, I have my function but I would like to change a parameter (Temperature,in case you're wondering) previously defined and have the 4 functions on the same plot. I'm looking for a option like *replot* in Gnuplot for instance. Here is what I've done so far using just Plots :

```
function L(v)
    defined the function here
    end;
plot(L,0,2000,title="Spectral Radiance",lw=2, xlabel = L"photon \ energy \ (cm^{-1})", 
    ylabel = L"W . m^{-2} . sr^{-1} . wavenumber^{-1}", label="300K")
```

So the Temperature has been previously defined for T = 2000 K, but now how can I change it to 3500,4500 and 5600 and display the results in the same plot ? Many thanks for any tips !

Comment: Use `plot!` with a bang.

Answer (score 6):

As @crstnbr says, in `Plots.jl` you can do:

```
using Plots
function L(v)
    v .* rand(100)
end;

p = plot()
for v in 1:4
    plot!(L(v), label="factor $v")
end
display(p)
```

Comment: And if you assign the plot object to a variable, you can use that variable as the first parameter to the plot!() call to indicate you are modyfying _that_ plot..

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ineed, ```plot!``` is working but I would like to find a way to modify the constant inside the function without redifining it and add a new ```plot!```line. For instance :
```function g(x)
    x + c
end;
c = 1
plot! (g,0,3)
c = 2
plot!(g,0,3)```
How can I redefine ```c``` each time ? I was looking for something like ```for c in [1,5,10]```but couldn't get it works.

Comment: Maybe: `g(x, c) = x + c; p = plot(); for c in [1, 5, 10] plot!(p, [g(x, c) for x ∈ 0:0.1:3]) end`?

Comment: @NilsGudat Thank you !! That is what I was looking for :)